# Completely plot line for a day before a gap

Tags: typescript, highcharts, time-series, timeserieschart

I use Highcharts/Highstock to plot a per-day timeseries. Some days might be missing, creating gaps in the plot. By default, the line of the day prior to a gap stops immediately at the beginning of that day. How would I make Highcharts draw the line up to the end of that day instead? The resulting gap would, in effect, be only 1 day wide.

Comment: Hi @Rochen, Did you consider using `ordinal` x-axis: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/xAxis.ordinal or `connectNulls` option: https://api.highcharts.com/highstock/series.line.connectNulls ?

Comment: @ppotaczek Thanks for your suggestions. `ordinal` is `true` so that the gaps are actually shown. I just tested `connectNulls` and it seems that it just draws over these gaps, which is not what I'm trying to achieve. The gaps should still be drawn as gaps, but a single non-gap day should be drawn out in its entirety, not just the dot at the start of that day.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the explanation. The only way I can see is to loop through your data, find the gaps and add one day value in timestamp (1000*60*60*24) to `x` values that are before the gaps.